# How to remove all \n's and make it as csv file of 5 columns?

Tags: python

```
[['\nAabhas\n'], ['\n\nThe sense, Feelings (1)\n\n'], ['\n5\n'], ['\nBoy\n'], ['\n\n']
```

In this list value between [] should come as a value in one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strip` is the best way, i think `regex` is expensive-

```
lst = [['\nAabhas\n'], ['\n\nThe sense, Feelings (1)\n\n'], ['\n5\n'], ['\nBoy\n'], ['\n\n']]

corrected_list = []

for i in lst:
    intm = []
    for j in i:
        intm.append(j.strip())
    corrected_list.append(intm)
print corrected_list
```

Or use oneliner list comprehension-

```
[[j.strip() for j in i]  for i in lst]
```

Output-

```
[['Aabhas'], ['The sense, Feelings (1)'], ['5'], ['Boy'], ['']]
```

Comment: Its showing syntax error at corrected_list.append(intm) i.e invalid syntax

Comment: Ah! I think you have changed the code while running- just copy and paste, care indentation error?

Comment: Ah! to it is running fine and printing `[['Aabhas'], ['The sense, Feelings (1)'], ['5'], ['Boy'], ['']]`

Comment: printing but more times.. Please re-enter the same please..      [['Aabhas']]
[['Aabhas'], ['The sense, Feelings (1)']]
[['Aabhas'], ['The sense, Feelings (1)'], ['5']]
[['Aabhas'], ['The sense, Feelings (1)'], ['5'], ['Boy']]
[['Aabhas'], ['The sense, Feelings (1)'], ['5'], ['Boy'], ['']]

Comment: go with the below approach that is -Enter exact `lst = [['\nAabhas\n'], ['\n\nThe sense, Feelings (1)\n\n'], ['\n5\n'], ['\nBoy\n'], ['\n\n']]
` in the console and hit ENTER then enter `[[j.strip() for j in i]  for i in lst]`

Comment: Yesss... Got it.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

use `strip()`

```
>>> l = '\nAabhas\n'
>>> l.strip()
'Aabhas'
>>>
```

Comment: Actually I need an answer like [['Aabhas'], ['The sense, Feelings (1)'], ['5'], ['Boy'], ['']] and then convert that into a csv file